# Binomial distribution in Probability and Statistics

Tags: probability

Look at the binomial distribution with $n$ trials and probability $p$ of success on each trial. For what value of $k$ is $P(x=k)$ maximized? The mode of the distribution. Hint consider using successive terms.

What i tried

I first write down the binomial distribution.

$$ P(x=k)= \left(  
\begin{array}{c}
    n \\
    k \\
  \end{array}
\right)p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$$

To maximize $P(x=k)$ i tried using techniques from calculus and find the derivative of $$  \left(  
\begin{array}{c}
    n \\
    k \\
  \end{array}
\right)p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$$

I then equate the derivative to $0$ in order to find the maximum point. Is my approach correct. Is there a better approach to doing it ?Could anyone explain. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of your function is not continuous, so no derivatives. Instead, you should consider quantities $P(x=k)/P(x=k−1)$. These quantities will be $>1$ up to some point $k^∗$, and then $\le 1$. Then $k^∗$ is the maximizer you need.